# migrating a yii2 website from windows to linux, broken links

Tags: php, linux, yii2, apache2

Recently I changed my development box from windows to linux. I'm trying to setup a yii2 site on my linux (mint 18.2) box. Previously I had the site running on a windows 7 box with xampp.

Here is my virtual host file on my mint box (/etc/apache2/site-available/tripcopilot.com).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin mine@email.com
    ServerName mysite.dev
    ServerAlias www.mysite.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/web

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I also added the following line to my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1    mysite.dev
```

then i enabled the site using

```
a2ensite mysite.dev.conf
```

So far with this setup the I can go to my browser and http://mysite.dev takes me to my homepage but when I try to navigate to any other page on the site i get a "page not found" error.

I thought this might have something to do with the fact that I'm using pretty urls... Here is my urlmanager component setup in yii2

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'rules' => [
                "home" => "site/index",
                "login" => "site/login",
                "sign-up" => "site/sign-up",
                "search" => "site/search"
            ],
        ],
```

After this I checked my apache settings to see if I allow for .htaccess files. Here is the current setup (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf).

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

So I changed it to the following

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

But now when I go to mysite.dev I get an "Internal Server Error". Here is the log entry from /var/log/apache2/error.log

```
[Tue Oct 17 15:30:37.366255 2017] [core:alert] [pid 17889] [client 127.0.0.1:41082] /var/www/mysite/web/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Is there something I am forgetting to do in my setup? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable the rewrite module. This is shipped with apache2 in many distributions, but not enabled by default. This should help

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Comment: Great thanks @clemens321 but this led to another issue, probably unrelated. Now I get a forbidden access error saying "You don't have permission to access / on this server" . when I try to go to home. Note this wasn't happening before I configured the htaccess file, I could see the home page correctly before that... Any ideas?

Comment: Please revert to the initial apache2.conf setup with only change `AllowOverride` from `None` to `All` and leave the `Require` line. `Allow from` is the old apache 2.2-syntax.